# Is there a way to overlay an interactive line plot on top of a video player in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to place an interactive line plot on top of a video player in JavaScript.

A few additional details:

- The video player needs to be 'fully functional' (i.e., play/pause, fast-forward, rewind, etc.)
- The graph would need to include both a x-axis and y-axis.
- The only graph interactivity that is needed is support for tool tips.

I am open to any tool(s) that may be able to accomplish this task.
I recognize that a fair amount of customization is likely to be required.

Comment: and where's the code you have tried so far... please post  it as well.

Comment: @AneesIjaz starting with code is precisely what I am trying to avoid. I am seeking guidance on a high-level approach for solving an obscure problem. Using a bottom-up approach here (e.g., trying to monkey patch D3) is extremely likely to result in very poorly designed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using , but getting the interactivity with both the video and the graph will be more difficult.

Here's an example with CSS grid to put the elements on top of each other. In order for you to be able to interact with the video, I set the chart to have `pointer-events: none;` I added a fake "point" div to the chart that adds back in pointer events. You can see this by the fact that it changes color on hover;

```css
video {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.chart {
  z-index: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.point {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.point:hover {
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.area {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <video controls src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/TearsOfSteel.mp4"></video>
  <div class="chart">
    <div class="point"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```